# How to get only Tweet (only posts) from the timeline?

Tags: django-rest-framework, getstream-io

Whenever tweet is created, it's activity is added to getStream production app.

```
class Tweet(models.Model, Activity):
    user = models.ForeignKey()
    text = models.CharField()

class Follow(models.Model, Activity): <- This is adding new activity to the timeline

def follow_feed_lisnner(~)
signal.post_save.connect(~)

class Like(models.Model, Activity): <- Like is adding to activity so timeline automatically shows who liked this post,
```

#### My Expectation:

**Feed**: only shows Tweet on timeline (I don't want to see who started to follow me, or liked any post) - Just Like Instagram!

**Notification**: Who started to follow me, Who liked my post, Who commented on my post.

views.py

```
feeds = feed_manager.get_news_feeds(request.user.id)
# get the newsfeed for user. 
activities = feeds.get('timeline').get()['results']
activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
```

#### Possible Solutions

- Use `python-stream` (more low level) to deal with this problem. (I don't know if it helps)
- Maybe I'm missing a cool feature of `stream-django`

How can we get only Tweet (Not Like, Follow or other activities which should be in notification) on the timeline?

Thank you

## UPDATE

If I understood correctly, this should work. Is this valid?

```
class Follow(models.Model, Activity):
    follower = 
    following

    @property
    def activity_author_feed(self):
        return 'notification' 

Activity 1: user A follows user B. 
Activity 1 goes to 'user' feed + 'notification' feed (not timeline feed) 
//notification feed name already exists so I don't need to create follow feed group

Activity 2: user B creates Post
Activity 2 goes to 'user' feed + 'timeline' feed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I'm assuming your Follow and Like models have a "user" field. If not, best update the question with the full Model classes and also confirm if you're setting up any other following relationships.*

The stream-django integration provides an 'Activity' model Mixin and the `FeedManager` model Manager. They work together to add activities to a Feed Group and Feed whose unique "feed id" is derived from the Model instance.

By default, the feed id is determined by the application wide `settings.USER_FEED` setting. That should work well for your `Tweet` model but is probably not what you want for the `Follow` and `Like` models. The activities associated with those models ideally belong in separate feeds. This can be setup by overriding the `Activity.activity_author_feed` property function.

```
class Follow(models.Model, Activity):
    # snipping fields

    @property
    def activity_author_feed(self):
        return 'Follow' # Must match a Feed Group defined in the Stream dashboard

    @property
    def activity_actor_attr(self):
        return self.author
```

To have to those activities copied into the notification feed, implement the `Activity.activity_notify()` function to return a list of target feeds.

```
    @property
    def activity_notify(self):
        return [feed_manager.get_notification_feed(self.user.id)]
```

Comment: So if I specify the Feed Group from dashboard in `activity_author_feed(self)`, the activity will be stored in 'Follow' group(in this case)? Could you see if I'm understanding correcrtly? I just updated the question. Please see **UPDATE**

Comment: The `activity_author_feed` function should return the name of the Feed Group you want to use, as a String. "Follow" looks like a consistent / logical name for the Feed Group with respect to the rest of your code sample and the stream-django integration. Though you are free to name your Feed Groups however you like.

Comment: thanks for answering. Then what is the point of the "notification" feed group? (I'm following stream-django tutorial and adding more features for my mobile app)

Comment: Well I'll first try and ask again if I need more. Thanks :)

Comment: The notification feeds provide for a different use case where an app should notify the user of certain events. As you said, you'd like to have Tweet activity appear in the users' timeline feeds and for the "like", "follow" and "comment" activities to appear separately in a notification feed.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean that I want to see them separately in a notification feed(It's like normal facebook notification). I wanted to see "like", "follow", "comment" activities in a notification in ascending time order. AND only Tweet activities in timeline. Is it what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes and no. Both "timelines" and "notification feeds" are simply "feeds" when it comes to the Stream API. When you store your notifications inside Stream, they're inside a feed. That'll take care of ordering and the seen/read statuses (just like Facebook). How the notifications are rendered and how the user may interact with them in your application is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I appreciate that.

Comment: here is further question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804843/how-to-serialize-the-array-of-specific-field-of-class-object