# How to serialize the array of specific field of class object (getStream)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, getstream-io

I'm trying to push `EnrichedActivity` data to `FeedSerializer`. I'm getting feed data using `getStream`

```
class FeedAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        feeds = feed_manager.get_news_feeds(request.user.id)
        # get the newsfeed for user.
        activities = feeds.get('timeline').get()['results']
        activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
        # I want to serialize only Outfit instances(object) from the activities.
        filtered_set = FeedSerializer(activities.getObject.convertToQueryset)
        json_output = { "feed" : filtered_list }
        return Response(json_output, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is the array data from `activities`

```
[
    EnrichedActivity(
        activity_data={
            'target': None, 'verb': 'outfit', 'actor': <User: georgiamason522>, 
            'to': [], 'foreign_id': 'outfit.Outfit:23',
            'id': 'x7x7bxxxxxxxxxxx3xbxx', 
            'object': <Outfit: georgiamason522 23>, // Data
            'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 14, 1, 36, 6, 833617), 'origin': 'user:17'}, 
            not_enriched_data={}), 
    EnrichedActivity(..., 'object': <Outfit: georgiamason522 22>,
]
```

I want to get this queryset from the array above,

```
filtered_set = ???
print(filtered_set)
<QuerySet [<Outfit: georgiamason522 23>, <Outfit: georgiamason522 22>]>
```

To put queryset into FeedSerializer.

```
FeedSerializer(filtered_set, many=True, context={'request': self.context['request']}).data
```

My question is...

1. **EnrichedActivity data seems like class object. How do we extract only `activity_data` > `object`.**
2. **Convert Extracted `object` data to the Queryset**

Here is pseudo code which can be right.

```
# This is Pseudo Code in my mind! This is not correct or can be not even close
filtered_set = [activity.activity_data.object].getQueryset for activity in activities
```

Please comment below if anything is not clear or need more information.

**UPDATE**

```
class FeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Outfit # I want to serialize Outfit Model instance 
                       # from feed in enriched list

    ...
```

Outfit model // you can think of it as like normal post

```
class Outfit(models.Model, Activity):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    @property
    def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type

    @property
    def activity_object_attr(self):
        return self

    @property
    def activity_notify(self):
        targets = [feed_manager.get_news_feeds(self.user.id)['timeline']]
```

Comment: @DwightGunning Is this question unrelated to getStream?

Comment: I assume FeedSerializer is inheriting from Django's built-in Serializer class. Therefore the challenge is that Serializer.serialize() takes a QuerySet as a parameter and the Enrich.enrich_actvities() function returns a list. There are a few ways to handle this and the best will depend on when and why you're using the Serializer. Can you share the relevant functions from your View?

Comment: I 'm not sure you need FeedSerializer code or Outfit model. Please let me know if you need more code :) thanks in advance

Comment: @DwightGunning I added the snippet of code under **UPDATE**

Comment: @DwightGunning I want to return serialized data of `Outfit`s which feed sends.

Comment: If you're just aiming to have the View emit a JSON representation of the activity, I would write a customer function to do this rather than implementing a full Django Serializer.

Comment: Maybe should I iterate through `activities`? Isn't it slower than Serializer?

Comment: The Django serializer is just iterating through the models in the QuerySet :)

Comment: I just posted my solution. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Follow-up question will be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863381/target-value-is-always-none-how-can-we-set-target-value-to-certain-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. Thanks to... @DwightGunning

```
    feed = []
    for activity in activities:
        outfit_instance = activity.__dict__.get('activity_data').get('object')
        data = FeedSerializer(
            outfit_instance,
            context={'request': request}).data
        feed.append(data)

    json_output = { "feed" : feed }
```