# `target` value is always None. How can we set `target` value to certain instance in Django Mode? (GetStream)

Tags: getstream-io

Here is notification that I got, and `activities` target is always None. How can we assign target instance in Model?

```
{'id': '6a4e1d107c07b2c7', 
...,
'activities': [
    EnrichedActivity(activity_data={'id': '6a4e1d18-e3b8-11e7-8080-80007c07b2c7', 'to': ['notification:1'], 'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 18, 5, 58, 5, 508124), 'foreign_id': 'comment.Comment:22', 'object': <Follow: johnmatt3 : jbaek7023>, 'actor': <User: johnmatt3>, 
    'target': None, <-- ALWAYS None. Why? 
    'verb': 'follow', 'origin': None}, not_enriched_data={}), 
    EnrichedActivity(activity_data={'id': '62b0e89c-e3b8-11e7-8080-80017680d313', 'to': ['notification:1'], 'time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 18, 5, 57, 52, 733814), 'foreign_id': 'follow.Follow:21', 'object': <Follow: jbaek7023433 : jbaek7023>, 'actor': <User: jbaek7023433>, 'target': None, 'verb': 'follow', 'origin': None}, not_enriched_data={})], 
'is_seen': True, 'verb': 'comment'},
```

Here is Comment class. I guess there would be a certain property to set the 'target'

```
class Comment(models.Model, Activity):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='follower')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    @property
    def activity_notify(self):
        SomeModel = self.content_type.model_class()
        ...
    return []
```

I need the specific property which can handle which instance should the `target`. such as...

```
@property  
def activity_target_attr(self): # this is not working
    print('test')
    target = blah blah
    return target
# expected output... 
# {id... activities: [EnrichedActivity(
# 'id': ..., 'target': <Outfit 32> ...),...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Target` is an optional property that may be used when [adding activities](https://getstream.io/docs/#adding-activities). For this reason the property is always included on the activities returned when a feed is retrieved.

If you're looking to work with the field inside your Django models, you should be able to simply define "target" field (probably of type a CharField) on the Model.

**Edit**: To clarify, in order to have the 'target' field sent into Stream as part of the Activity, it needs be included via the `extra_activity_data()` function.

The fields automatically included from the model are `actor`, `verb`, `object` and `time` and shown in the `Activity.create_activity()` function ([source](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django/blob/91122b63fba9f75f0ba468dbd53ac0b0f3706b3f/stream_django/activity.py#L111)).

Comment: But I can't define "target" field in class. :( It has object_id and content_type for target. Is there any @property for target??

Comment: Also I tried to add "target" field on Comment model (like above) but target always returns None.

Comment: comment_instance.target prints the instance which I want for `target`. It's weird.

Comment: I solved the problem using extra_activity_data(self)! Now it's ready to deploy. Awesome work guys! I love getStream

Answer (score 0):

I looked up getStream Activity class and there was no way to pass `target` instance.

For my case, I wanted to pass the target's content type and its id.

```
@property
def extra_activity_data(self):
    SomeModel = self.content_type.model_class()
    object_id = self.object_id
    qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(id=self.object_id)
    if qs:
        dict_object = '%s:%s' % (self.content_type, self.object_id)
        return {'target_address': dict_object}
    return None
```

Thanks!